# Display double in immediate window different in vs2013/vs2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have the following line of code:

```
double r = 0.000056262413896897934;
```

In visual studio 2013, I go to the immediate windows and type:

```
?r
```

And the results display the double's value:

```
0.000056262413896897934
```

However if I bring up the project in Visual Studio 2017 and type this in the immediate window:

```
?r
```

It display the following result (exponential format):

```
5.6262413896897934E-05
```

I would like Visual Studio 2017 to display the format in the same way as Visual Studio 2013 does:

```
0.000056262413896897934
```

Not just for this variable or this solution but as a permanent setting.  Does anyone know how to do this?  Thanks in advance

Comment: The `DebuggerDisplay` attribute at the assembly level, maybe.  Not a permanent setting, but semi-permanent.

Comment: Tools > Options > Debugging > General, tick the "Use the legacy C# and VB expression handlers" checkbox.  It is permanent, but the message box does remind you that getting used to this minor quirk is easier today than it will be tomorrow.

Comment: It's best not to use the legacy C# and VB expression handlers. While changing that might change this behavior it has a far wider impact. While it's not ideal the workaround below is a better long term solution. If you'd like to change the default for all users open an issue on developer feedback.
(Disclosure: I work on the VS debugger)

Comment: Andy, you had it working so nice in vs2013!  Why default to exponential format which is so tricky?  At first glance someone could think it's 5.63...  The truth being that the value is less than 1! Very unfriendly to the eyes, just my two cents.

Answer (score 1):

As @Amy mentioned you can use `DebuggerDisplay` to change the appearance of an object in the debugger. As `double` is a built in type you can't just change its implementation. For cases like this the debugger has a feature where it will load in `DebuggerDisplay` implementations externally that are implemented in `autoexp.cs`

1. Open (as admin) the `autoexep.cs` file which should be in a directory that looks like:
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\16\Preview\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers\Original` obviously that will change with your VS version but if you search for `autoexp.cs` you'll find it.
2. In that file, add the code below: `[assembly: DebuggerDisplay(@"{ToString(""F17""),nq}", Target = typeof(Double))]` that's going to tell the debugger to basically execute `ToString("F17")` whenever it's displaying a `double`.
3. Open a Developer Command Prompt as admin and navigate to where `autoexp.cs` is e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\16\Preview\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers\Original`
4. Build the file with `csc /t:library autoexp.cs`
5. Reload VS and run your scenario

You should then see something like:

[image: Immediate window evaluating a double]

More info on `DebuggerDisplay` is in our docs over at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-the-debuggerdisplay-attribute?view=vs-2017 and more info on the `ToString` implementation for `Double` is over at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2.

Comment: Andy, I really appreciate your response.  Thank you very much!  But very sad that exponential format is the default now. Why default to exponential format which is so tricky? At first glance someone could think it's 5.63... The truth being that the value is less than 1! Very unfriendly to the eyes, just my two cents.

Comment: I don't think it's a case of it being difficult. The ToString implementation contains a way to visualize the a double in either way (and many others). Again, it's not VS that changed here but the implementation in .NET that changed the ToString implementation. You can look at the .NET Core version at: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/62c70143cfbb08bbf03b5b8aad60c2add84a0d9e/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Double.cs. Which just calls into NumberFormat/NumberToDouble. I have no idea when/if that changed. It could be worth opening an issue on GitHub to find out more.

Comment: Though, one reason for the change might simply be that a exponent and mantissa more accurately represent a double than a decimal. Given that the underlying storage is that way.